# Square Bracket SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Our software currently reads square brackets [] as needing to enter a field into for the user.

I've trying to add a report in for a few users but can't get this to function properly as the PIVOT within the report won't let me remove the square brackets.

Does anyone know of a replacement for this?

```
PIVOT
(
    SUM(A)
    FOR MonthYear
    IN ([01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],[11],[12])
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to conditional aggregation:

```
select . . . ,
       sum(case when monthyear = '01' then a else 0 end) as mon_01,
       sum(case when monthyear = '02' then a else 0 end) as mon_02,
       . . . 
from . . .
group by . . .;
```